# How to use a comma separated value column on an IN statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below, the relate column contains ids that references to itself using the id column

```
id  name    relate
1   James   1
2   John    1-2
3   Bob     1-2-3
```

I am working on the query below but is not working

```
SELECT id, name, (
                   SELECT zrelate =
                    Stuff
                        (
                            (
                                SELECT ', ' + name AS [text()] FROM
                                    (
                                        SELECT name
                                        FROM myTable
                                        WHERE id IN REPLACE(relate,'-',',')
                                    ) x
                                For XML PATH ('')
                            ),1,1,''
                        )
                 ) 'zrelate'
FROM myTable
```

The expected output is

```
id  name    zrelate
1   James   James
2   John    James,John
3   Bob     James,John,Bob
```

This is a badly designed table from an unknown database but is currently loaded in SQL 2012. The goal is to extract the data for the user and drop the table for the obvious reason.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest fixing your design here.

Comment: ^^^this. Agreed. Your denormalised design is the root cause of the problem. If you find yourself storing multiple values in a single field then it's time to think about using a second table. Then you won't need to create convoluted queries and string manipulation to access a straightforward piece of information.

Comment: this data was a hand-over and we are actually trying to export the data and then decommission this server

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: I am not sure from where the data is originally from but it is currently loaded in MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken data model.  Here are some reasons:

- You should not be storing multiple values in a string.
- You should not be storing numbers as strings.
- SQL has a great way to store lists of values; it is called a table.
- SQL Server has pretty poor string processing capabilities.
- And having to parse these strings significantly slows down the processing.

Sometimes you are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions.  If you are stuck with this data model, you can do something in the more recent versions of SQL Server:

```
select t.*, t2.relates_to_names
from mytable t outer apply
     (select string_agg(t2.name, ',') within group (order by t2.id) as relates_to_names
      from mytable t2
      where t2.id in (select try_convert(int, s.value)
                      from string_slit(t.relates_to, '-') s
                     )
     ) t2;
```

However, you should put your effort into designing a second table, that would look something like this:

```
id    relates_to_id
1          1
2          1
2          2
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a hand over data and the current goal is to extract the data and drop this table for the same reason as you have mentioned. Unfortunately, the string_split function is not available on SQL 2012.

Comment: @Ruben_PH . . . You can easily find a string split function if you Google "SQL Server string split".  For the aggregation, you will need to use the XML approach.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the design, fix the problem. Instead you should have 2 tables, one with the people, and another with the relationships.

This gives you a design like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                         [name] varchar(5));
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Relation(ParentID int, ChildId int);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Relation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ParentPerson FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES dbo.Person(id);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Relation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ChildPerson FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES dbo.Person(id);
```

And your data would look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (id, [name])
VALUES (1,'James'),
       (2,'John'),
       (3,'Bob')

INSERT INTO dbo.Relation
VALUES(1,1),
      (2,1),
      (2,1),
      (3,1),
      (3,2),
      (3,2);
```

And then, finally, you get a normalised data set like this:

```sql
SELECT P.id,
       P.name,
       C.name
FROM dbo.Person P
     JOIN dbo.Relation R ON P.id = R.ParentID
     JOIN dbo.Person C ON R.ChildId = C.id;
```